# mongoose find newest version for each category

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

With this collection:

```
const formSch = new Schema({
    formversion: Number,
    type: String,
    blocks: [{...}],
});

const Form = mongoose.model('form', formSch);
```

I would like to find for each type of form the latest version.

Right now I'm manually processing the results after fetching them from db, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient approach (i.e. mapreduce or aggregate):

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => Form.find().exec()
        .then((forms) => {
            const formversions = forms.reduce((fv, curr, idx) => {
                if (!fv[curr.type] || fv[curr.type].version < curr.formversion) {
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
                    fv[curr.type] = { idx, version: curr.formversion };
                }
                return fv;
            }, {});
            const formTypes = Object.keys(formversions);

            return formTypes.map((type) => {
                const idx = formversions[type].idx;
                return forms[idx];
            });
        })
        .then(res.json.bind(res))
        .catch(next));
```

The main problem I found with mapreduce is how to keep a global variable that tracks the greatest current version in order to compare with current element.

So with this elements:

```
[
    {
        "formversion": 1,
        "type": "Expedient",
        "blocks": [...],
    },
    {
        "formversion": 2,
        "type": "Expedient",
        "blocks": [...],
    },
    {
        "formversion": 1,
        "type": "Repte",
        "blocks": [...],
    },
    {
        "formversion": 2,
        "type": "Repte",
        "blocks": [...],
    },
    {
        "formversion": 3,
        "type": "Repte",
        "blocks": [...],
    },
    {
        "formversion": 4,
        "type": "Repte",
        "blocks": [...],
    },
]
```

The result should be:

```
[
    {
        "formversion": 2,
        "type": "Expedient",
        "blocks": [...],
    },
    {
        "formversion": 4,
        "type": "Repte",
        "blocks": [...],
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort by `formversion` and pick the first one:

```
Form.aggregate([
    {$sort:{"formversion":-1}},
    {$group:{"_id":"$type", "form":{$first:"$$ROOT"}}},
    {$project:{"_id":"$form._id", "type":"$_id", "blocks":"$form.blocks"}}
], function (err, result) {
    ....
});
```

Comment: But I need the first version for each type of form, not the first version for all forms, I update the data example to ilustrate it

Comment: Ouch, my bad. I have updated the answer. Aggregation is the way to go. Not sure if mongoose hydrate the result into models tho.

Comment: Great! is it possible to `$project` full elements? (meaning `{ $project: { "form": "$root" } }`

Comment: No,  unfortunately you need to specify  all fields.  Saying that,  the project stage is optional. If you remove it,  the result will have 2 fields: "_id"  and "form".  The later will contain the whole document.